# How to setup Yaws webserver on Ubuntu Server 10.10?

Tags: yaws, ubuntu-server

I would like to develop some web applications using Erlang and the Yaws webserver. But I'm having problem with setting up Yaws on Ubuntu Server 10.10.

First I updated my Ubuntu system with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

### Installing Yaws with apt-get

I installed Yaws with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install yaws
```

But when I run Yaws with `yaws -i` I get this error message:

```
Yaws: Bad conf: "Can't find config file "
```

Then I tried to start Yaws with `yaws -i --conf /etc/yaws/yaws.conf` but then I got this error message:

```
Yaws: Bad conf: "Can't open config file /etc/yaws/yaws.conf"
```

I guess there is some problems with the file permissions.

### Installing Yaws using the latest stable build

Now I tried to install Yaws using the latest stable build:

```
 wget http://yaws.hyber.org/download/yaws-1.89.tar.gz
 tar xfz yaws-1.89.tar.gz
 sudo apt-get install gcc
 cd yaws
 ./configure && make
```

But then I get errors during compilation:

```
epam.c:2: fatal error: pam_appl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [epam.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jonas/yaws-1.89/c_src`
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

**How can I install Yaws webserver on Ubuntu Server 10.10?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what version of Yaws apt-get will give you, so I recommend always installing the latest stable build from [the Yaws website](http://yaws.hyber.org/). Before you attempt to build it, though, make sure you first install the build dependencies for Yaws:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep yaws
```

Assuming you already have Erlang installed, you should then be able to successfully configure and make the latest stable build.

You can always visit the Yaws [Build Config and Run page](http://yaws.hyber.org/configuration.yaws) for general build and install information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit /etc/yaws/yaws.conf with text editor, you must be root. Don't forget about /etc/yaws/conf.d/ directory, especially about the servers names. 
Uncomment "id = debian_yaws" (or similar) - will be easier to shut down the server.
 To check config run server with:
yaws
If everything is OK, run server as daemon:
yaws -D -heart
  Important - check if there are some hidden files in directory after edition config files! This can be old versions of config files - this must be deleted!